# SetCurrentItem ViewPager2 after notifying changes in adapter not animating

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewpager2

I am using the `ViewPager2` class and i am working with a mutable collection of `Fragment`s.
I have a dynamic `ViewPager2` which contains initially a unique fragment at rank 0.
I also have 2 buttons in this fragment.

According to which button is being clicked, a new fragment is added inside the Adapter's fragment list and i am calling this method :

`myAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1, myAdapter.getItemCount())`

I can also use `notifyItemChanged(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1)` it's working.

The problem is that i call `setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1, true)` right after the notify call and it's like if the `PageTransformer` was not called <=> the smoothscroll is not working.

I thought it was because of some delay between the notify-action and the call of setCurrentItem() but it appears it is not. What i did is :

`new Handler().postDelayed(() -> { viewPager.setCurrentItem(...) }, 200)`

I have also tried to do : `viewPager.post(() -> viewPager.setCurrentItem(...))` but it doesn't help either.

Here is my adapter class :

```
 private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

        ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentArrayList;

        public ProfileViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity, ArrayList<Fragment> fragments) {
            super(fragmentActivity);
            this.fragmentArrayList = fragments;
        }
        
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
            return fragmentArrayList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean containsItem(long itemId) {
            return super.containsItem(itemId);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return fragmentArrayList.size();
        }
    }
```

In the adapter class, I have also tried without overriding `getItemViewType(int position)`, then with the `super` call in `getItemId(int position)` and finally without all above methods except `getItemCount()` and `createFragments(int position)`.

All resultats are the same.

What else can i try ?
Thanks

Comment: Do you found a solution? I have the same issue.
My ViewPager2 has an inner viewPager (a calendar), the bottom ViewPager2 (not the calendar) has its swipe disabled, the way to travel its fragments is via bottom navigation, I noticed that it is possible to travel to the next page, only after interacting with the top recyclerView (calendar), either by long pressing or swipe navigating its pages.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I am not developing in Android native code anymore, i went to Flutter and it's much easier for this kind of things :). Sorry that i can't provide a solution for this question, but this will remain open !

Comment: Thanks Tom for your response :), I think I solved this, just don't remember how, I believe the solution was for large content pagination, simply stop using the FragmentStateAdapter and deal directly with the RecyclerViews' viewHolders, and for fixed size VPs (with add and remove functionality) load everything onCreate and limit accessibility to pages by intercepting touch events in a Deque'd way (creating the illusion of add and remove).

Comment: The issue with the VP2 is it is bound to the viewLifeCycle hence its contents cannot refresh reactively without killing its owner's (view) lifecycle (or something on that vein.... can't remember)